# immutable js: make a function more.. functional

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

I have a reducer function that operates on [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) records, a `Calendar`:

```
const Calendar = new Record({
    'events': new List(), // list of Events
});
```

which is a list of `Event`s:

```
const Event = new Record({
    'start': null,
    'end': null,
    'title': null,
});
```

I want to add new Events from Javascript objects to this list and return a new `Calendar` record, but only if the objects are not in the list already:

```
(state = new Calendar)=> {

    const receivedEvent = new Event({
        start: <a date>,
        end: <another date>,
        title: <a string>,
    });

    let newState;

    if (state.get('events').contains(receivedEvent)){
        newState = state;
    } else {
        newState = state
            .updateIn(['events'], (events)=> events.push(receivedEvent));
    }

    return newState;  
}
```

This is the best that I can do right now at 4 AM, but it seems like a terrible approach.

Is there a way to make better use of functional paradigms such as those provided by Immutable to complete this same task?

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you have a `Set` of events.  If you change the data type, then asking questions like `includes` (or `contains`) become easier.

Comment: In your reducer, you may use https://github.com/engineforce/ImmutableAssign, which is a lightweight immutable helper that allows you to continue working with POJO (Plain Old JavaScript Object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dealing with a collection where membership is important then you probably want to use a [Set](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Set) not a List.

A set is just a collection of unique values.

```
const Calendar = new Record({
  'events': new Set(), // set of Events
});
```

Then you can add the event to the set without worrying about ending up with duplicate values. The implementation of the data structure prevents you from having to check whether it already contains the value.

```
(state = new Calendar) =>
  state.updateIn(['events'], calendar => calendar.add(new Event({
    start: <a date>,
    end: <another date>,
    title: <a string>,
  }));
```

As you are representing a calendar, the order in which events are added is probably not important, as you can use the event dates themselves to sort as a list, otherwise, you could use an [OrderedSet](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedSet) to preserve the ordering.

Comment: minor note, shouldn't it be `state.get('events').add(...)`?

Comment: actually, sorry, this returns the substate, not the state, so this should work instead:

       `return state.updateIn(['events'], (events)=> events.add(new Event({
            start: <a date>,
            end: <another date>,
            title: <a string>,
        })));`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that `List.contains` will compare each `Event` to `receivedEvent` using `===`.

Even though `receivedEvent` may share the same attributes as one already stored in your state, they aren't the *same* object.

Example:

```
const x = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const y = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const z = x;

x === y; // -> false
x === x; // -> true
x === z; // -> true
```

So, you will need to compare each attribute of the `receivedEvent` to each instance you're comparing it to. Thankfully, there's the the [handy `Immutable.is` method](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/is), which you could use like so:

```
if (state.get('events').some(event => Immutable.is(receivedEvent, event))) {
    // already exists in events
} else {
    // doesn't already exist in events
}
```